# Hölder condition with Not of Bounded Variation

Tags: bounded-variation

Let $\alpha$ $\in ]0, 1]$.
$f : [a, b]$ $\to \Bbb R$ is said to satisfy a uniform Holder condition
with exponent $\alpha$if there is some positive constant $M$ such that
$\mid f(x_1) - f(x_2)\mid  \lt M\mid x_1 - x_2\mid$, for all $x_1, x_2 \in [a, b]$

Is there any function that satifies a uniform Holder condition with exponent $\alpha$and which is not of bounded variation?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/136445/191404.

Comment: @Vim if a function is not BV $\Rightarrow$ not differentiable?

Comment: what do you mean by differentiable? At any point or at at least one point?

Comment: Anyway, [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/855021/191404) contradicts your statement.

Comment: @Vim I had just learned the concept of Bounded Variation, but I 've just been provided with the definition, but not with tis meaning. Why does BV concept is meaningful to mathematicians?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation.

Comment: If I have proved that $f=x^a\sin(1/x^b)$ on $(0,1]$ ,$f(0)=0$ is of BV if and only if $a>b$. Can we try the function $f=x^\alpha\sin(1/x)$?

Comment: Where does the $\alpha$ enter? Do you mean $|\,f(x_1)-f(x_2)\,|\lt M|\,x_1-x_2\,|^\alpha$?

Answer (score 3):

The Weierstrass function is Hölder continuous but it is not BV.

Comment: if a function is not BV $\Rightarrow$ not differentiable?

Comment: If a function is BV then is it differentiable a.e. The Weierstrass' function is not differentiable at any point.